# I want add reference to renderere in property

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

**This is my code;**

```html
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="#ff1500" iOS="Transparent"></OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
 </StackLayout>
```

**I want add reference to renderere in property like this:**

```html
<StackLayout>
    <StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" Android="{controls:GradientColors StartColor="#373737" EndColor="#191919"}" iOS="Transparent"></OnPlatform>
    </StackLayout.BackgroundColor>
</StackLayout>
```

**How I do it?**

Comment: You need to create BindibleProperty

Comment: Can you give me example how to do it? thank

Comment: One of many: https://xamarinhelp.com/bindable-properties-xamarin-forms/ If you need to change the color using property then binding prop will do but if you need also to use custom specifics (like gradients, etc) then @JordyDieltjens is right, you also need custom renderers

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is make a renderer for Stacklayout, lets say CustomStackLayout.

And than on each platform you change the backgroundcolor.